# Block access to a webpage without using a log in system

Tags: php, .htaccess

What would be the best way to block access to a webpage without requiring some form of username and password combination? Access would be limited to people I personally gave the information to bypass security measures to.

No personal data is going to be stored, and it doesn't need to be overly security conscious, it's just a simple browser game I have made, and I'm getting fed up with bots pressing buttons.

A login is too inconvenient to input every time I want to access the page, be it database-driven or .htaccess-based.

I tried using a unique query string that needs to be in place in the URL for the page to load, but that actually seems to be generating **more** spam submissions.

I was thinking of limiting access by IP address via the .htaccess, but those can easily be spoofed, right?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to set cookie in users browser and have a simple logic to increment the cookie value when user visits the page.

Comment: In this case you mean 'limiting' as in 'blocking access'? You could require a cookie to be set, but there is no reason to believe a bot has cookies enabled.

Comment: Yes, "blocking". I have amended the question title to make this clearer.

Comment: If you're meant to be the only user during the development stage, use htaccess to restrict the access to your current IP, or at least your IP block in case it changes dinamically.

Comment: You mention a game. Is it a game using forms of some kind or are you using something like flash/java/something similar?

Comment: Form-based. The buttons submit information to a DB, which the results of are displayed on the page.

Comment: For generic spambots, an empty hidden (`display:none`, not `type=hidden`) input field and a hidden input field with a static anti-spam string in it is surprisingly effective (or at least used to). Since bots automatically detect those, and try to fill either of them in. If they are more talored to your game, you can try having a random/semi-random input field name and a random/semi-random anti-spam input field that should not be filled in so it is more difficult to code for. The problem with the last one that how hard you make it, it will always be possible to determine what field to fill in.

Comment: a correctly configured `.htpasswd` file and `.htaccess` should remember your binary ip address. i don't know about `apache`, but i setup one of my development servers with `nginx` and a `.htpasswd` file and i only had to authenticate once, or anytime i restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a name that's not obvious and making it not findable with permissions?  For example:
xyz.com/secret/secretpageJJKS.htm
and make sure anonymous users can't execute the secret folder but can read it or vice versa.  The permissions of the folder always seem backwards to me.

Albert

Comment: But he wants people to be able to play his game. Hiding his file is not going to help in any way...

Comment: He wrote: "Access would be limited to people I personally gave the information to bypass security measures to."  With my idea, it would be hidden from all except those people that he gives the URL to. This would keep bots out as long as nobody posted the link to a page that a search engine found. He could also add a simple question like "What is 2 plus 3?" or "Who's buried in grant's tomb?".